# How to set the result of a command to a variable

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I'm trying to display the line number of the first 'string' occurrence from a long string variable and set the result to another variable.

To display the line of the first 'string" occurrence, I use:

```
grep -n -m 1 String Filename.csv | cut -f1 -d:
```

It works fine. However, I would like to get the 'String' value from the array variable and Filename.csv switch to the long string. For example:

```
string[0]='Column2'

Query="Select Column1,
              Column2,
              Column3
       From   dual"
```

And now:

```
Line_number=$(grep -n -m 1 ${string[0]} "$Query" | cut -f1 -d:)
echo $Line_number
```

The result should be: 2

But it displays:

```
grep: "Select Column1,
                  Column2,
                  Column3
           From   dual  "   No such file or directory
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Am extra `(` in `$((grep -n -m 1 ${string[0]} "$Query" |cut -f1 -d:)` ?

Comment: You are trying to read the content of Query as filenames, use `<<< "$Query"`

Comment: The canonical is *[How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437)*. Despite the unspecific title, it covers the case of ***(variable) input to the external command*** (in a (Bash) variable. But is this question sufficiently different?

Answer (score 0):

Change the script to:

```
string[0]='Column2'

Query="Select Column1,\n
              Column2,\n
              Column3\n
       From   dual"

Line_number=$(echo $Query | grep -n -m 1 ${string[0]} |cut -f1 -d:)
echo $Line_number
```

And see what you will get.

Comment: Hi, There is no error, but result is all the time 1 (seems to be all in one line), I put \n but I got an error with invalid character (from database)

Comment: @maciek2791 you shouldn't use grep like "grep $pattern $Query" where Query is not the filename but a string, only "echo $Query |grep $pattern" is available. ```man grep``` to see the detail.

Comment: Can you describe the changes and/or the gist/idea of the solution (so every reader does not have to run diff)? You can [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38307414/edit) (but ***without*** "Update:", "Edit:", or similar).

Comment: Re *"And see what you will get."*: Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

The [AWK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) solution for this would be:

```
arr=$(echo "${string[@]}")
line_number=$(awk -v var="$arr" '$0 ~ var{print NR;exit 0}' <<<"$Query")
echo "$line_number"
```

---

**What is happening here?**

- We can't directly pass a Bash array to AWK, so we `echo`ed it and store it in `arr`.
- `var="$arr"` stores the shell variable to AWK variable `var`.
- `$0 ~ var{print NR;exit 0}` checks(~) for the pattern, prints the line number of the first occurrence and exit the script.
- `<<<` in Bash is called [here-string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) which helps you pass strings to commands.

---

The [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) solution for this would be:

```
arr=$(echo "${string[@]}")
line_number=$(sed -n "/$arr/{=;q}" <<<"$Query")
echo "$line_number"
```

---

**What is happening here?**

- We can't directly pass a bash array to `sed`, so we `echo`ed it and stored it in `arr`.
- `-n` option suppresses the normal output.
- `/$arr/{=;q}` checks for the pattern(`/stuff/`), print the line number(=) and then quits(q) sed.